# Derive Rigid Transform Matrix from Axes and Origin

Tags: math, matrix, transformation

I'm trying to derive the matrix of a rigid transform to map between two coordinate spaces. I have the origin and the axis directions of the target coordinate space in terms of the known coordinate space; does anyone know how I can solve for the 4x4 rigid transformation matrix given these?

So, in other words, I have two coordinate spaces, A and B, and I know

```
Point3D originOfBInA;
Vector3D xAxisOfBInA; // Unit vector
Vector3D yAxisOfBInA; // Unit vector
Vector3D yAxisOfBInA; // Unit vector
```

And I'm trying to find the 4x4 matrix

```
Matrix4x4 AtoB;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First construct the 4x4 matrix for the change of basis (call it M) by using your unit vectors (Ax, Ay, Az) and the origin (T) as column vectors:

```
M = 
   [Ax Ay Az T]    <-- 3x4
   [0  0  0  1]
```

To transform the coordinates of a point p (specified with respect to frame A) to q (with respect to frame B), just multiply by the inverse of M:

q = M<sup>-1</sup>p